# What happens when a Service receives a start command after calling stopSelf()

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-service-binding

I use an Activity to bind to a Service and from there I call `startService()` to have the Service perform a task.
When the Service completes the task it calls `stopSelf()`.  Naturally, the Service doesn't stop until my Activity unbinds. What happens when the Activity calls `startService()` again after the Service's call to `stopSelf()`.  Will the Service get destroyed once the Activity unbinds or will it continue to run?

Comment: I would expect it to continue to run, but you'd probably want to test that scenario.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I would expect it to run as well. Somehow Android rarely behaves how I would expect it to (is that just me?).  In this case, however, it behaves as expected, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through trial and error it appears that the service continues to run.
The activity's call to `startService()` effectively cancels the Services prior call to `stopSelf()`.
The code for my experiment can be found here. https://gist.github.com/Proper-Job/56d22b36714e3339be05

Answer (score 0):

Your Service is destroyed at the point of the stopSelf()

Comment: No, at the point of stopSelf() it is bound by an activity, hence it continues to run at that point.

Comment: Actually it gets destroyed and after that You're just leaking a thread and the Service object, at least until the thread terminates.

Comment: @TaRanLaYal: Not while it's still bound. A service is destroyed on a `stopService()` call if and only if there are no outstanding bound connections to it.